# Vanity URL, .htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess

Im trying to add vanity url to my web page, but its not working.
So far I have tried with

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)[^.]$ index.php?page=$1 [nc]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

but its not working, and i dont know .htaccess syntax!

All I got is this error:

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, admin@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.

Do you know how can I do this?
How can I make.htaccess to redirect my url which looks like www.page.com/vanityurl to index.php?page = $1 but page variable must now be "vanityurl".

I tried this on localhost and on my web server but i get the same error!

Thank you! For your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `error_log` to find out what is going on.

It might be that your `httpd.conf` is not set to allow rewrite rules to be specified in `.htaccess`

If that is the case then you will see a message in the error log like:

```
RewriteEngine not allowed here
```

In order to use rewrite rules in `.htaccess` the `AllowOverride` setting needs to either include `FileInfo` or be set to `All` e.g

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```